# "!empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'"

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to work on a Face Recognition system in Python OpenCV but I keep getting the following error

> "!empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'"

This is the code that I'm using:

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import pickle

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
image_dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "foto")

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

current_id = 0
label_ids = {}
y_labels = []
x_train = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("png") or file.endswith("jpg"):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            label = os.path.basename(root).replace(" ", "-").lower()
            #print(label, path)
            if not label in label_ids:
                label_ids[label] = current_id
                current_id += 1
            id_ = label_ids[label]
            #print(label_ids)
            #y_labels.append(label) # some number
            #x_train.append(path) # verify this image, turn into a NUMPY 
 arrray, GRAY
            pil_image = Image.open(path).convert("L") # grayscale
            size = (550, 550)
            final_image = pil_image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            image_array = np.array(final_image, "uint8")
            #print(image_array)
            faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_array, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)

            for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                roi = image_array[y:y+h, x:x+w]
                x_train.append(roi)
                y_labels.append(id_)


#print(y_labels)
#print(x_train)

with open("pickles/face-labels.pickle", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(label_ids, f)

recognizer.train(x_train, np.array(y_labels))
recognizer.save("recognizers/face-trainner.yml")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Include full error stack please.

Comment: File "bllablla.py", line 36, in <module>
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_array, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.5) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1698: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the full path to the file.
Example:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\working_Dir\\data\\codes\\OpenCV\\classifiers\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
```

You can download these codes from the github Repo here : [Face Detection with Python using OpenCV](https://github.com/parulnith/Face-Detection-in-Python-using-OpenCV)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you need to add double slashes instead of single ones.

Answer (score 0):

git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

Comment: Please explain the subtle differences to the other answers, how they work and why they solve the problem. Try to make obvious which benefit your solution provides over the others.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give full path of your haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml file
like this:-"C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\cv2\data\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml"

Answer (score -1):

Xml file is missing.

Try to give full path directly like this.

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\opencv\sources\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

more importantly the file should be in **C Directory**