# !_map1.empty() in function 'cv::remap'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I am trying to build this stereo vision obstacle distance detection system using a tutorial, but keep hitting a brick wall and could use some advice, please.

When running either [disparity2depth](https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/Depth-Perception-Using-Stereo-Camera/python/disparity2depth_calib.py) or [obstacle_avoidance](https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/Depth-Perception-Using-Stereo-Camera/python/obstacle_avoidance.py) files, I get the same xml file read errors and remap error at both [rectification](https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/Depth-Perception-Using-Stereo-Camera/python/disparity2depth_calib.py#L84) [lines](https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/Depth-Perception-Using-Stereo-Camera/python/obstacle_avoidance.py#L109).

```
\[error:0@2.333\] global D:\\a\\opencv-python\\opencv-python\\opencv\\modules\\core\\src\\persistence.cpp (505) cv::FileStorage::Impl::open Can't open file: '../data/stereo_rectify_maps
.xml' in read mode
\[error:0@2.336\] global D:\\a\\opencv-python\\opencv-python\\opencv\\modules\\core\\src\\persistence.cpp (505) cv::FileStorage::Impl::open Can't open file: '../data/depth_estimation_pa
rams_py.xml' in read mode
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\XXXXXXXXXX\\ObstacleAvoidSystem\\Depth-Perception-Using-Stereo-Camera\\disparity2depth_calib.py", line 84, in \<module\>
Left_nice= cv2.remap(imgL_gray,
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\\a\\opencv-python\\opencv-python\\opencv\\modules\\imgproc\\src\\imgwarp.cpp:1703: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !\_map1.empty() in function 'cv::remap'
```

Different `cv2.FileStorage.open` (filename, flags) have been tried but return similar errors.
Opening in write mode also returned similar errors (as above).

I also tried the full directory path by researching similar (indirect) errors, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120605/empty-in-function-cvcascadeclassifierdetectmultiscale) and got the following error:

`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the CWD.

`assert os.path.exists("data/stereo_rectify_maps.xml"), os.getcwd()`

Solved the issue. At first the statement passed/returned nothing, which made me think the file might be corrupted. However, after reloading the IDE and running again, the statement returned the path it was looking for.